# Convert strings to json in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, json

Is it possible to read these strings (was converted to strings from json format) into php arrays?

jQuery:

```
  $.ajax({

            type: 'GET',
            url: 'index.php?task=search&wtd=ul',
            data: $('#fupdate').serialize()+'&derulo='+$('#getdbresult').val(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('.the-modal').html('Updating...');
            }, 
            success: function(d){
                $('.the-modal').html(d);
                console.log(d);
            }

    });
```

PHP:

`var_dump(json_decode("{$_REQUEST['derulo']}", true));`

VALUES:

```
string(379)"[{\"target_detail_id\":\"66351031\",\"first_name\":\"Dorothy\",\"last_name\":\"Smith\",\"company\":\"Active Money Now\",\"sic_code\":\"\",\"position\":\"\",\"target\":\"1300572544\",\"website\":\"\",\"email\":\"dorothy@activemoney.com.au\",\"email_status\":\"\",\"country\":\"Australia\",\"city\":\"Broken Hill\",\"postal_code\":\"2880\",\"address\":\"Po Box 41\",\"note\":\"\"}]"
```

RESULT:

`NULL`

I tried using `json_decode` but nothing appears.
Also looked at using `implode` to separate strings accordingly.
But is there any other way to this?

`EDIT:`

It works with: `$object = (json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['derulo'])));`

Comment: Maybe you should use **json_decode**?...

Comment: I have rephrase the question, I was did use json_decode. typo error

Comment: If so, what means "nothing appears"? Did you try `json_decode('...json...', true);`?

Comment: Yes. Also tried that, but when print_r'ed nothing appears..

Comment: Post your actuall function call and how you checked the result. The example is valid json, there is no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: You're mixing up php and JavaScript/JQuery in your code example. Please make it clearer. Just post the exact code snippet!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) ("*Decodes a JSON string*") instead of [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) ("*Returns the JSON representation of a value*").

Assuming your input is correct (and the example presented by you is), the return value will be an object *representing* the JSON data. You can also get the result as an array (see the docs for parameter reference).

---

EDIT: There must be another problem with your code, please post your complete code.
(My guess would be that you are not checking the returned value but expect json_decode to modify the parameter by reference and only check the parameter variable - that would explain why "nothing happens")

The following works:

([Ideone snippet](http://ideone.com/O9vz7w))

**PHP code:**

```
<?php

$json = <<<JSON
[{"target_detail_id":"66351031","first_name":"Dorothy","last_name":"Smith","company":"Active Money Now","sic_code":"","position":"","target":"1300572544","website":"","email":"dorothy@activemoney.com.au","email_status":"","country":"Australia","city":"Broken Hill","postal_code":"2880","address":"Po Box 41","note":""}]
JSON;

$object = json_decode($json);
$array = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($object);
var_dump($array);
```

**output:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (15) {
    ["target_detail_id"]=>
    string(8) "66351031"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(7) "Dorothy"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(5) "Smith"
    ["company"]=>
    string(16) "Active Money Now"
    ["sic_code"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["position"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["target"]=>
    string(10) "1300572544"
    ["website"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["email"]=>
    string(26) "dorothy@activemoney.com.au"
    ["email_status"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["country"]=>
    string(9) "Australia"
    ["city"]=>
    string(11) "Broken Hill"
    ["postal_code"]=>
    string(4) "2880"
    ["address"]=>
    string(9) "Po Box 41"
    ["note"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(15) {
    ["target_detail_id"]=>
    string(8) "66351031"
    ["first_name"]=>
    string(7) "Dorothy"
    ["last_name"]=>
    string(5) "Smith"
    ["company"]=>
    string(16) "Active Money Now"
    ["sic_code"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["position"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["target"]=>
    string(10) "1300572544"
    ["website"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["email"]=>
    string(26) "dorothy@activemoney.com.au"
    ["email_status"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["country"]=>
    string(9) "Australia"
    ["city"]=>
    string(11) "Broken Hill"
    ["postal_code"]=>
    string(4) "2880"
    ["address"]=>
    string(9) "Po Box 41"
    ["note"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

---

EDIT2:

1. You don't need quotes around the `json_decode` parameter, just use

   ```
   json_decode($_REQUEST['derulo'], true);
   ```

   But this is not what is causing problems (it's just inefficient, php has to parse another variable in a string).
2. Your php snippet works, so you must be getting wrong data from the query. You can easily check for that with

   ```
   var_dump($_REQUEST['derulo']);
   ```

   You shouldn't be mixing sending data in both the url and over `data`, when using a `GET` request or switch to POST. I'd recommend letting jQuery take care of the serialization of the data, e.g.

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'index.php',
       data: {
         'task':'search',
         'wtd':'ul',
         'derulo':JSON.stringify($('#getdbresult').val())
       },
       beforeSend: function(){
           $('.the-modal').html('Updating...');
       }, 
       success: function(d){
           $('.the-modal').html(d);
           console.log(d);
       }
     });
   ```

Comment: I have rephrase the question, I did use json_decode.

Comment: I think the `$_REQUEST` values is not enclosed as string. That's is why json_decode can't read the value as string

Comment: Tried your suggested jquery, the result now has `string(379)` at the beginning using `var_dump` will edit the result on the question

Answer (score 0):

The code you attached to your question is already formatted in json. So you need to *decode* it with json_decode function. It returns an object, just typecast it to an array.
Be aware that the json code is an array by itself (everything is inside square brackets), so we must refer to the first item ($item[0]).

```
$json = '[{"target_detail_id":"66351031","first_name":"Dorothy",...';
$items = json_decode($json);
$items_array = (array) $items[0];
```

Json_decode offers also an option to return automatically an array: json_decode($json, true).